# How to apply animation effect to a View without using time interpolation

Tags: android, animation, interpolation

I am trying to change View's position, scale and alpha with touch events (at the time). When user touches a view and makes some movement the view should be effected. It is like applying combined animation via touch distance instead of time.

I can also calculate interpolated value for distance. For example if I move my finger half of the target distance I have the interpolation value 0,5.

Actually I could achieve this by changing the margins around the view but it only works with ImageView. Otherwise the position of the elements change during applying the effects. (Like TextViews in RelativeLayout)

So I thought that I can create a combined animation and use my own interpolated value instead of the time interpolation. I hope it is possible.

Comment: I want to use animation if I can apply my own interpolation value. I think using animation class is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way:

1. Create custom `FrameLayout` and call `setWillNotDraw(false);`
2. Load the image as `Bitmap` to be drawn
3. Catch touch event's inside the `FrameLayout`
4. Implement proper drawing and transformation(position, alpha, scale) in `onDraw` method for the `Bitmap`

Comment: Yes but Animation class uses this custom interpolator with time. So creating and setting custom interpolator doesn't solve my problem. I need to apply effect with distance not with time.

Comment: Okay, then it might be hard to use Animation, I guess you are looking for proper transformation to the View based on your variables?

Comment: Yes exactly. Changing alpha and position is ok. But resizing is hard.